# netty java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer caused by RST,ACK

Tags: netty, haproxy, ioexception

We use haproxy to do load balance, and the netty server keep to rise "java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer"
below is the exception stack:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1055)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:112)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:510)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:467)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:381)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:742)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use tcpdump to dump the network data of the netty server, and see below

[image]
10.125.137.11,10.125.137.13,10.125.137.14 are hapxory server ip
Seems haproxy just send [RST,ACK] to finish a health check.

So, I am wondering if I have to handle this situation in my handler(like check exception is IOException, just ignore it, because the log is full of this exception) , or it should be handled by netty it self?

Answer (score 0):

If the HAProxy sends a RST it is expected. You can just filter out the exception in a `ChannelHandler` implementation by overriding the `exceptionCaught(...)` method if you not care.

Comment: I have think about it, but I worried if I just ignore the IOException, maybe same real error will be ignored too